# MySQL user with limited admin permission

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a MySQL user that can create new databases and manage only them (create/drop tables,) without the possibility of managing other schemas.
Is that possible? What permission does he require?
I tried mixing DBDesigner and DBManager but it seems that he can edit everything or nothing (neither his databases).

Comment: AFAIA, this can only be done if you know in advance the name(s) of the databases that the user will create.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help. Check this out: [MySQL RefMan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `tester123` by a PHP variable or anything you'd like as the username and database name.

Replace `%` next to tester123@ with your desired hostname.

lines explained:

1. create user
2. let user login but don't do anything
3. create database
4. let user access this database
5. commit changes

here we go:

```
CREATE USER 'tester123'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '***';

GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'tester123'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '***' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `tester123` ;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `tester123` . * TO 'tester123'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Hint:

This can easily be done and gets explained by `phpMyAdmin`, *users -> create user -> grant access to database named after the user or `<user_*>`*

Answer (score -2):

Download mysql workbench. In the server manager you will find users / priviliges. Here you can tailor make your users very easily.

Comment: the question is "Which permissions to i have to give a user so that he can only create and manage his own database and no other schemas?"

Comment: And this can be done in the users & priveliges of mysql workbench!

Comment: "I would like to create a mysql user that can create new databases and manage only them (create/drop tables, ...) without the possibility of managing other schemas. Is that possible?"

Comment: I don't think recommending a tool for a task like this is appropriate when it should be first be done through command line (if it were to be possible with no programmation, which in this case is uncertain)

Comment: I disagree. The workbench tool is excellent for these kind of tasks. Its very easy to get the complete overview of the users priviliges and schema the user has access to. If you can downgrade my answer, you can better provide a better answer then also.

Comment: Most database servers won't let you connect through your home internet ip anyways for security reason, making the workbench tool useless. I'd expect a sql query as a solution